# Understanding Mathematical Notations

Tags: general-topology, matrices, discrete-mathematics

Please help me in clarifying few maths symbols represented in the following texts **[1] and [2]**

[1]

". As before, let's assume a training dataset of images $$x_i∈R^D, $$each associated with a label $$y_i$$. Here $$i=1…N\;and\; y_i∈1…K.$$ That is, we have **N** examples (each with a dimensionality **D**) and **K** distinct categories. For example, in CIFAR-10 we have a training set of **N** = 50,000 images, each with **D** = 32 x 32 x 3 = 3072 pixels, and **K** = 10, since there are 10 distinct classes (dog, cat, car, etc). We will now define the score function $$f:R^D↦R^K$$ that maps the raw image pixels to class scores."

[2]
"$$x=[1,1,1,1]\; and\; two\; weight\; vectors\; w_1=[1,0,0,0]\;, w_2=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]\;w_2=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25].\; Then\; w^T_1x=w^T_2x=1 $$"

**Could anyone explain what does this mean**
[1]
"$$x_i∈R^D,\;  What\; i \;think\; is\; that \;x_i,\; has\; a \;range \;of\; [1,D] $$
 $$ f:R^D↦R^K\; could\; mean\; a \;function \;defined \;from \;D \;sets\; of\; images\; to \;K \;sets$$

[2]

$$w^T_1x=w^T_2x=1 \;Does\;it\;mean\;w^T \;is \;the \;transpose\; of \;w \;vector$$"

Am I right in my interpretations?

Comment: It would be better if the question said where the quoted material came from. The source appears to be http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/ or some other copy of the same text.

Comment: yes @David the source is from http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation of $R^D$ is incorrect.

$R^D$ means the set of functions with domain $D$ and range $R$. So, $x_i \in R^D$ means that $x_i$ is a function $x_i : D \to R$: input an element of $D$ and the function $x_i$ outputs an element of $R$.

Here's how I remember this. One learns in algebra that $R^2$ means the set of ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1,x_2 \in R$. You can equally well think of the ordered pair $(x_1,x_2)$ as a function whose domain is $\{1,2\}$ and whose range is $R$: input $1$ and this function outputs $x_1 \in R$; input $2$ and this function outputs $x_2 \in R$. Thus, you can equally well think of $R^2$ as $R^D$ where $D$ is the set with $2$ elements $\{1,2\}$.

$f : R^D \to R^K$ is a function whose domain is $R^D$ and whose range is $R^K$. So, $f$ takes as its input a function with domain $D$ and range $R$, and produces as its output a function with domain $K$ and range $R$.

Comment: I think in this case the original authors were thinking of the elements of $R^D$ as $D$-tuplets rather than as functions. I could be wrong, but it's a CS topic (http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/), the authors seem more interested in computation than in precise language (e.g., writing "pixel" when they mean one color component of a pixel), and given an $x_i \in R^D$, they immediately assume the "pixels" of $x_i$ are "flattened out to a single column vector of shape [D x 1]."

Answer (score 1):

$R^D$ is the set of $D$-dimensional vectors with real components.
For example if $D=3$ then $R^D$ is the set of all vectors of the form $(x,y,z)$ where $x,y,z$ are real numbers. Here it is the same except $D=3072$, you have one component for each pixel.

$f:R^D\longrightarrow R^K$ is a function whose domain is $R^D$ and whose range is $R^K$, ie the set of $K$-dimensional vectors with real components.

In practice you have a picture, represented by an element of $R^D$ denoted by $x_i$ and you want to associate a label (to put it in a class) to $x_i$ (there are $K$ labels). In order to do this, you are going to compute the score of $x_i$ for each of the $K$ classes. So you'll a $K$-dimensional vector. That is why $f$'s domain is $R^D$ and $f$'s range is $R^K$.

Yes, $w^T$ is the transpose of $w$. So you have $w^Tx=w_1x_1+w_2x_2+\dots +w_nx_n$ (here $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of $x$, this is not a vector).

Comment: If we wanted to nitpick the source text, we could suggest that if they were going to use matrix language for their vectors they would have done better by writing $x=[1,1,1,1]^T$ to define $x$ as a column vector, since they clearly wanted it to be one.

Comment: Yes you're right, the $x_i$'s and $w_i$'s should be columns.